# WPF Return value from Thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, backgroundworker, return-value

I'm trying to open a WPF Form from external Aplication with Thread.. I want to open the Form (as Dialog) and after that I need return a response (object) to the Main Aplication... I've actually the Error InvalidOperationException when I tray to access the member.. I tried also with BackgroundWorker but I cannot resolve the problem.

Comment: From another application?  From your description you are trying to do something that is at a level far above where you currently appear to be.  You need to [edit] and clarify.

Comment: could you post the  code where the exception is thrown?

Answer (score -1):

```
  var t = Task<RETURNED_OBJECT>.Factory.StartNew(() => DIALOG());
  t.Result;
```

In this case, Dialog() will be executed in a new Task. When the thread closes (eg. Dialog closes) the result of that dialog is stored in t.Result

Comment: it is not guaranteed that the task will be executed in proper synchronization context, which must be the main UI thread.